# C# String.Format args

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting

I have an array like this:

```
object[] args
```

and need to insert those args in a string, for example:

```
str = String.Format("Her name is {0} and she's {1} years old", args);
```

instead of:

```
str = String.Format("Her name is {0} and she's {1} years old", args[0], args[1]);
```

NOTE: Actually the first line of code worked! But args[1] was missing! Sorry and thank you. Points for every one :)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Your first example should work fine, provided there are at least two objects in the array args.

```
object[] args = new object[] { "Alice", 2 };
str = String.Format("Her name is {0} and she's {1} years old", args);
```

Answer (score 16):

It should work just the way you want it to.  The String class has the following Format method definition:

```
public static string Format(string format, params object[] args);
```

Seeing as how the "args" in your example is an array of objects, it should fit right in.

Answer (score 15):

If you do not know how many array elements are in the arguments array, try using string.Join().

```
string.Format("Arguments passed in to the program are: {0}", string.Join(" ", args));
```

Specifically in your example:

```
string.Format("Her name is {0} years old", string.Join(" and she's ", args));
```

Personally, I don't like hard-coded structures of an array object.  That's too much to remember throughout the application and makes it hard to maintain.  I would rather turn the arguments into a "Person" object with a constructor that accepts the array, and overload the ToString() to display the specific information about the object members.

```
class Person
{
    private string m_sName;
    private string m_sAge;

    public Person(string[] args)
    {
        m_sName = args[0];
        m_sAge = args[1];
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Her name is {0} and she's {1} years old.", m_sName, m_sAge);
    }
}
```

So you can construct a "Person" object and display the message when called.

```
var oNewPerson = new Person(args);
console.WriteLine(oNewPerson.ToString());
```

This is very similar to a Microsoft example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but either of those should work, considering that one of the signatures for the String.Format() function is

```
Public Shared Function Format(ByVal format As String, ByVal ParamArray args() As Object) As String
```

More junk I copied from Visual Studio:

**Summary:**
Replaces the format item in a specified System.String with the text equivalent of the value of a corresponding System.Object instance in a specified array.

**Parameters:**
format: A composite format string.
args: An System.Object array containing zero or more objects to format.

**Return Values:**
A copy of format in which the format items have been replaced by the System.String equivalent of the corresponding instances of System.Object in args.

**Exceptions:**
System.ArgumentNullException: format or args is null.
System.FormatException: format is invalid.  -or- The number indicating an argument to format is less than zero, or greater than or equal to the length of the args array.

-- Oops on the VB, but you get the point.

Comment: I love that the API definition you gave was for VB.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your second code-block would do what I think you are trying to accomplish.

```
string.Format("Hello {0}, {1} and {2}", new object[] { "World", "Foo", "Bar" });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str = String.Format("Her name is {0} and she's {1} years old", args);
```

Should work when args is of type object[].

Answer (score 2):

Both your examples do the same thing - String.Format has an overload which accepts an object[] instead of specifying each argument separately.

Answer (score 1):

Did you even try the first line? Did you see that it should work the same as the second?